# Javascript vairables empty unless I debug code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a function which makes a ajax call and gets a list of vehicle make.

```
var car_make_list_target_id = 'car_make';
var make_year_list_select_id = 'years';
var car_model_list_target_id = 'car_model';function get_car_model(){

var car_model_initial_target_html = '<option value="">--Select Model--</option>';
//Grab the chosen value on first select list change
var selectvalue = $('#car_make').val();
alert('first alert ' + selectvalue);
var yearvalue = $('#' + make_year_list_select_id).val();
//Display 'loading' status in the target select list
$('#' + car_model_list_target_id).html('<option value="">Loading Car Models</option>');

if(selectvalue === ""){
    //Display initial prompt in target select if blank value selected
    $('#' + car_model_list_target_id).html(car_model_initial_target_html);
} else{
    //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_model.php?make=' + selectvalue + '&year=' + yearvalue,
        success: function(output){
            //alert(output);
            $('#' + car_model_list_target_id).html(output);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

I also have a php if loop to see is session isset. Now I want to display these values within the drop down list if the session is set.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['vehicle_info'])){
    echo '<script>'
    .'$("#states option[value=' . $_SESSION['vehicle_info']['state'] . ']").attr("selected","selected");'
    .'$("#years option[value=' . $_SESSION['vehicle_info']['year'] . ']").attr("selected","selected");'
    . ' $("#years").prop("disabled", false);'
    . ' $("#car_make").prop("disabled", false);'
    . ' $("#car_model").prop("disabled", false);'
    . 'get_car_make();//This works'
    . 'get_car_model();//This does not work unless I debug javascript'
    . '</script>';
}
```

The issue is unless I set a breakpoint within the get_car_model on the following lines

```
var selectvalue = $('#car_make').val();
alert('first alert ' + selectvalue);
```

the var selectvalue is blank, but if I leave the breakpoint it will alert the value of the option and will display correctly. I have been beating my head for the last 4 hours and I have not been able to figure this out. Is this normal browser behavior or am I missing something? Any input will be great.

Comment: i dont know what is the issue but try with timeout

Comment: Your comment says *"Grab the chosen value on first select list change"* but you're not setting up a `change` event handler.

Comment: @RaymondFeliciano: Offsite links like that are not appropriate for SO. The primary purpose of SO is to be useful *for others in the future*. External links rot. Set up an [MCVE](/help/mcve) here on-site using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I have set and change event for the ddl and even pass the value of the option but it still will not work so I removed it. As for the link sorry I figured you would like to have something to see.

Comment: @Ishan Shah: Setting the timeout seems to work so far. Thanks

Comment: so i am adding my comment to main answer and mark as accepted so others may useful.